# How to find the distance to the nearest edge on a MultiDiGraph using OSMNx

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm trying to find the distance in a MultiDiGraph from a given location to the closest edge and closest node. 
For example the specified location with `latitude = 51.217220` and `longitude = 4.418535`. Firstly we compose a `MultiDiGraph` at that location with a radius of 350m. Here is the code:

```
import osmnx as ox
lat = 51.217220
lon = 4.418535
G = ox.graph_from_point((lat, lon), network_type='drive', distance=350, simplify=True)
```

The OSMNx package has 2 valuable functions for my project: `get_nearest_edge()` and `get_nearest_node()`. `get_nearest_node()` finds the nearest node and returns it's ID. It also has an built-in option to return the distance to this nearest node:

```
ox.get_nearest_node(G, (lat,lon), method='haversine', return_dist=True)
```

`get_nearest_edge` finds the nearest edge and returns the ID's of the 2 nodes that define the edge (each edge consists of 2 nodes being connected). However there's is no built-in option to get the distance to this edge.

How can I calculate the distance from the given location to the nearest edge?

Answer (score 1):

Yes so, my head function is get_d_to_nearest_edge(). This code is given below:

```
def get_d_to_nearest_edge(latitude, longitude, file_name):
    # get nearest node incident to nearest edge to reference point
    G = ox.load_graphml(filename=file_name, folder='BAPenvironment')
    distance = get_nearest_edge(G, (latitude, longitude))
    print(type(distance))
    print(distance)
```

In this function I call the method get_nearest_edge(), however it's rewritten as @Sparky05 told me before. The code is below:

```
def get_nearest_edge(G, point):
    """
    Return the nearest edge to a pair of coordinates. Pass in a graph and a tuple
    with the coordinates. We first get all the edges in the graph. Secondly we compute
    the euclidean distance from the coordinates to the segments determined by each edge.
    The last step is to sort the edge segments in ascending order based on the distance
    from the coordinates to the edge. In the end, the first element in the list of edges
    will be the closest edge that we will return as a tuple containing the shapely
    geometry and the u, v nodes.
    Parameters
    ----------
    G : networkx multidigraph
    point : tuple
        The (lat, lng) or (y, x) point for which we will find the nearest edge
        in the graph
    Returns
    -------
    closest_edge_to_point : tuple (shapely.geometry, u, v)
        A geometry object representing the segment and the coordinates of the two
        nodes that determine the edge section, u and v, the OSM ids of the nodes.
    """
    start_time = time.time()

    gdf = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, fill_edge_geometry=True)
    graph_edges = gdf[["geometry", "u", "v"]].values.tolist()

    edges_with_distances = [
        (
            graph_edge,
            ox.Point(tuple(reversed(point))).distance(graph_edge[0])
        )
        for graph_edge in graph_edges
    ]

    edges_with_distances = sorted(edges_with_distances, key=lambda x: x[1])
    closest_edge_to_point, distance = edges_with_distances[0]

    geometry, u, v = closest_edge_to_point

    ox.log('Found nearest edge ({}) to point {} in {:,.2f} seconds'.format((u, v), point, time.time() - start_time))
    print(type(distance))
    print(distance)
    return geometry, u, v, distance
```

The thing is, when I check the type within the get_nearest_edge() function, the type is float, just like @Sparky05 said and the distance is found. But however when I return this values to my head function get_d_to_nearest_edge() the value is a tuple, and can't be printed as a float.

However what's even more important is that the distance that I find is totally incorrect. The output: 0.00025593968794827235 and the real distance should be 26.13 meters, any help?

Comment: You should not have used an answer to add this new code and rather had modified your question (or opened a new one): in your `get_d_to_nearest_edge` method you have an error. If you are only interested in the distance this should be `_, _, _, distance = get_nearest_edge(...)`. For your second point with the value of the distance, keep in mind that the value returned is the distance between GPS positions (longitude, latitude), probably you need to search for a conversion.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this forum and didn't know how to use this. I will use your feedback for my future questions. Now back to the code... Well I just need to find the distance from a given location to the nearest edge, so I guess the distance is perpendicular on the edge. I'm working with (lon,lat) already, so why is there another conversion needed?

Comment: You need to check which distance is calculated by ox.Point(..).distance, then you know what that returned value means. If you have tried it and still haven't found an answer, open here a new question with the new question. Stackoverflow tries to focus on one think for each question, such that other with similar question (and not many similar ones ;)) find the answer.

Comment: @Sparky05 I opened a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344467

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of the original [`get_nearest_edge`](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/46ed807f870e3bede78f7e494e98490df470bd42/osmnx/geo_utils.py#L210) method and in your local copy of the method, you only need to replace [line 247](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/46ed807f870e3bede78f7e494e98490df470bd42/osmnx/geo_utils.py#L247) with:

```
closet_edge_to_point, distance = edges_with_distances[0]
```

and the return statement with

```
return geometry, u, v, distance
```

You could also create an issue for this at the GitHub page of `osmnx` and propose this as new feature.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However when doing this, when printing the distance, nothing appears on the screen. Any ideas why?

Comment: Check the type of the result (print(type(distance)) - it should be float. Or try adding a print to the whole list of results (print(edges_with_distances))